# The property outliercolor of python plotly graph_objects box marker is not working (possible bug)

Tags: python, colors, plotly, box

I think I've found a bug in the class plotly.graph_objects.box Marker, because the property outliercolor is not working. I followed the reference in https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Box.html#plotly.graph_objects.box.Marker.outliercolor, but it wont make any difference to change the outliers color.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, to_hex

df_plot = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
cat_var = "species"
num_var = "petal_length"

lvls = df_plot[cat_var].unique()
n_levels = len(lvls)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_palette", ["#111539", "#97A1D9"])
my_palette = [to_hex(j) for j in  [cmap(i/n_levels) for i in np.array(range(n_levels))]]

boxes = []
for l in range(n_levels):
    boxes += [
        go.Box(
            name = lvls[l],
            y = df_plot.loc[df_plot.loc[:, cat_var] == lvls[l], num_var].values,
            width = 0.4,
            boxpoints = "outliers",
            marker = {
                "outliercolor": "red", ### there may be a plotly.go bug here
                "color": my_palette[l],
                "size": 30,
                "opacity": 0.5
            }
        )
    ]
fig = go.Figure(data = boxes)
fig.update_layout(
    font = dict(
        size = 18
    ),
    showlegend = False,
    plot_bgcolor = "white",
    hoverlabel = dict(
        font_size = 18,
        font_family = "Rockwell"
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does indeed appear to be a bug in Plotly - this can be submitted as a bug report to the Plotly team.

It is worth noting that modifying `boxpoints = "outliers"` to `boxpoints = "suspectedoutliers"` produces markers with a different color so `suspectedoutliers` behaves as expected. However, you can't use `suspectedoutliers` in place of `outliers` as suspected outliers are only a subset of all outliers.

You can achieve the desired behavior by plotting the outliers manually. To do this, you would still set `boxpoints=outliers`, but then plot the outliers as individual scatter points with the desired color over the outliers generated by Plotly.

This is a bit intensive because this requires a rewrite of the algorithm to determine outliers *exactly* as the Plotly library performs this calculation. And unfortunately, you cannot extract Q1, Q3 or other statistics from go.Box or from Plotly in any way [as these computations are performed by the Javascript under the hood when the figure renders](https://community.plotly.com/t/extracting-box-plot-statistics/37383).

The first thing to note is that calculating Q1 and Q3 differs between different Python libraries: Plotly outlines their methods in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#choosing-the-algorithm-for-computing-quartiles), explaining that they use [Method #10 in this short paper](http://jse.amstat.org/v14n3/langford.html) to calculate percentiles.

In Python, the function to calculate percentiles using Method #10 (linear interpolation) looks like this:

```
## calculate quartiles as outlined in the plotly documentation 
def get_percentile(data, p):
    data.sort()
    n = len(data)
    x = n*p + 0.5
    x1, x2 = floor(x), ceil(x)
    y1, y2 = data[x1-1], data[x2-1] # account for zero-indexing
    return y1 + ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1))*(y2 - y1)
```

Now to extract outliers from a data set, you subset the data: anything below (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) or above (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR) where IQR = Q3 - Q1 is considered an outlier.

Putting this all together:

```
from math import floor, ceil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, to_hex

df_plot = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
cat_var = "species"
num_var = "petal_length"

lvls = df_plot[cat_var].unique()
n_levels = len(lvls)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_palette", ["#111539", "#97A1D9"])
my_palette = [to_hex(j) for j in  [cmap(i/n_levels) for i in np.array(range(n_levels))]]

## calculate quartiles as outlined in the plotly documentation 
def get_percentile(data, p):
    data.sort()
    n = len(data)
    x = n*p + 0.5
    x1, x2 = floor(n*p), ceil(n*p)
    y1, y2 = data[x1-1], data[x2-1] # account for zero-indexing
    return y1 + ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1))*(y2 - y1)

def get_fences(data):
    q1, q3 = get_percentile(data, 0.25), get_percentile(data, 0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1
    return (q1 - (1.5*iqr), q3 + (1.5*iqr))

boxes = []
for l in range(n_levels):
    data = df_plot.loc[df_plot.loc[:, cat_var] == lvls[l], num_var].values
    outliers = data[(data < get_fences(data)[0]) | (data > get_fences(data)[1])]
    print(outliers)
    boxes += [
        go.Box(
            name = lvls[l],
            y = data,
            width = 0.4,
            boxpoints = "outliers",
            marker = {
                "outliercolor": "red", ### there may be a plotly.go bug here
                "color": my_palette[l],
                "size": 30,
                "opacity": 0.5
            }
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x = [lvls[l]]*len("outliers"),
            y = outliers,
            mode = 'markers',
            marker=dict(color="red", size=28, opacity=0.5)
        )
    ]
fig = go.Figure(data = boxes)
fig.update_layout(
    font = dict(
        size = 18
    ),
    showlegend = False,
    plot_bgcolor = "white",
    hoverlabel = dict(
        font_size = 18,
        font_family = "Rockwell"
    )
)
fig.show()
```

[image]

As a way to check our work, you will notice that the slightly smaller manually added outliers match the outliers determined by Plotly. (You can make the manually added outliers larger to obscure the Plotly generated outliers that aren't the desired color)

Comment: Funny enough, I've just found out this behavior for "suspectedoutliers". I was a bit resilient to go this way of ploting scatters like a mask, it really works, but it would be very much appreciated if Plotly itself fixed this issue. But anyways, I'll use this idea. Thanks