# How to specify the percentiles in a pyplot box?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python, percentile

Say I have the simplest of scripts

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# set up an array of 20 data points, with 20 as the median value
y = [1,14,14,15,16,18,18,19,19,20,20,23,24,26,27,27,28,29,33,54]

data = [
    go.Box(
        y=y,
        boxpoints='outliers' # display only outlying data points
    )
]
pyo.plot(data, filename='box2.html')
```

With that I have the following

[image: box plot]

My question is, I understand this is for the 25% and 75% percentile?
Is there a way to change the value of the percentiles shown?

Comment: Please refer to the [official API reference](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Box.html), where you can specify the calculation method for q1 and q3, and there is an explanation of q1q3.

Comment: Yes, there is an explanation of the calculation methods. But there is no explanation on how to specify other percentiles (this is possible in matplotlib)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your own [precomputed quartiles](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-with-precomputed-quartiles) and make Q1 and Q3 whatever values you like, and then calculate whatever percentile you want Q1 and Q3 to be.

In another question about plotly boxplots that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68332945/the-property-outliercolor-of-python-plotly-graph-objects-box-marker-is-not-worki), I wrote a function that computes the percentiles using the same method plotly uses.

You'll need to specify the lowerfence, (new) Q1, median, (new) Q3, and upperfence in the `update_traces` method. Here is what I get if I set Q1 = 5th percentile and Q3 = 95th percentile:

```
from math import floor, ceil
from tkinter.messagebox import YES
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

## calculate quartiles as outlined in the plotly documentation 
def get_percentile(data, p):
    data.sort()
    n = len(data)
    x = n*p + 0.5
    x1, x2 = floor(x), ceil(x)
    y1, y2 = data[x1-1], data[x2-1] # account for zero-indexing
    print(x1, x2, y1, y2)
    return y1 + ((x - x1) / (x2 - x1))*(y2 - y1)

# set up an array of 20 data points, with 20 as the median value
y = [1,14,14,15,16,18,18,19,19,20,20,23,24,26,27,27,28,29,33,54]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_traces(go.Box(
    y=y,
    boxpoints='outliers' # display only outlying data points
))

q1, median, q3 = get_percentile(y, 0.05), get_percentile(y, 0.50), get_percentile(y, 0.95)

fig.update_traces(q1=[q1], median=[median],
                  q3=[q3], lowerfence=[min(y)],
                  upperfence=[max(y)], orientation='v')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I like how you can manipulate the lowerfence and upperfence. I would like some help how I can use it with ```boxmode='group'```

Comment: would you be able to post that as a separate question with more details?

Comment: I posted my question where maybe you could, please, contribute -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106793/how-to-group-data-and-also-specify-the-percentiles-in-a-go-box

Answer (score 1):

- as per other comment and answer.  Quartiles are quartiles and can be calculated in other ways
- if you wan t percentiles in addition to quartiles,  you can add additional lines to the figure

below demonstrates adding 9 percentile lines to the figure

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# set up an array of 20 data points, with 20 as the median value
y = [1,14,14,15,16,18,18,19,19,20,20,23,24,26,27,27,28,29,33,54]

data = [
    go.Box(
        y=y,
        boxpoints='outliers' # display only outlying data points
    )
]

fig = go.Figure(data) #.add_traces(go.Bar(x=np.repeat(["trace 0"],9), y=[np.percentile(y, q) for q in np.linspace(10,90,9)]))

fig.add_traces(
    px.line(
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "y": np.repeat(np.percentile(y, np.linspace(10, 90, 9)), 2),
                "x": np.tile([0.4, 0.6], 9),
                "p": np.repeat(np.linspace(10, 90, 9), 2),
            }
        ),
        x="x",
        y="y",
        color="p",
    )
    .update_traces(showlegend=False, xaxis="x2")
    .data
).update_layout(xaxis2={"overlaying": "x", "visible": False, "range": [0, 1]})
```

[image]